# Download layers from arcGIS online in python

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, layers, arcgis-online, maps

How can I get layers/maps from arcgis online in Python? I mean to download layers from Arcgis online in python, just like publishing.
I've searched about it in the documentation of Arcgis 10.2.2, but I  only found publishing.

At the end, I want to write a Python script that will download, automaticly, layers\feature classes from the arcgis online, by specific areas.
Please help me.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to explain in more detail what you mean by getting layers/maps, please?  I suspect others are having the same problem understanding how downloading layers is like publishing, or what you mean by downloading layers.  Can you please expand your description of what it is you want to do, what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/Esri/ArcREST

Comment: https://github.com/Schwanksta/python-arcgis-rest-query